# Adding local file to python search path when running a script in a different directory

Tags: python, bash, sys.path

I wrote a python script "Script.py" that works when I copy it into the directory I want to run it in. I run this script a lot, so I wanted to add it to .bashrc so I don't have to copy it into every directory I need to run it in.

So the script is in directory:

```
/home/pythonscripts/Script.py
```

Now I want to run this script in the directory:

```
/home/Documents/Test1/
```

Part of the script is importing a different file (this is unique to each test case). The location of this file is:

```
/home/Documents/Test1/equations.py
```

If I start in the "Test1" directory and run "Script.py" I get the following error:

```
 File "/home/python/Script.py", line 115, in <module>
     import equations
 ImportError: No module named 'equations'
```

If I place the script into the directory that I'm running this from (/home/Documents/Test1/), there is no error. What I figure is that the script is looking for the equations.py file in the "/home/python" directory, not the local one where I'm running the script from.

My question is how do I tell the script to look in the local directory for the equations.py file in a general way so that I can run Script.py from any directory and have it know to look in the one it's running in for equations.py?

Comment: You can `import sys` and append the desired path to `sys.path`, or do a relative import

Comment: That's just the thing, I can't figure out how to add the directory I'm in to sys.path

I could do it if I added exactly the directory I'm in. But then it wouldn't be general enough to when I decide to run the script in the next directory.

Comment: You can `import os` and try `dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` or `cwd = os.getcwd()`

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current working directory (the directory you were in when running the script)

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

now you can import the file using the full path `cwd/myfile.py` using importlib (in python 3). for more info see [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

as a side note, when working with files and the filesystem, I personally really like working with this package:
https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/plant

Comment: Thanks!
The first part of your answer was super helpful. And I'm going to read up on the second part to learn more